# How to create an aggregate to find min and max value of an integer column and return output in text format?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function where I am specifying the table and column but I require an aggregate that can work for any table and column for similar output

```
create function min_max_val()
returns text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $$
  declare
  mmv text;
  begin
  select format('%s - %s',min(id),max(id) )min_max_vals into mmv from towns;
  return mmv;
 end;
$$ ;

    min_max_vals
---------------------
 1000001 - 11000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to dynamic sql as seen below

as seen in the last query, you need to use the result of the query and also address the return values

> ```
> CREATE TABLE towns ("id" int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO towns VALUEs (1),(2),(3)
> ```

> ```
> select format('%s - %s',min(id),max(id) )min_max_vals  from towns;
> ```
>
> ```
> | min_max_vals |
> | :----------- |
> | 1 - 3        |
> ```

> ```
> create function min_max_val( cols text,tables text)
> returns SETOF RECORD
>  LANGUAGE plpgsql
>  AS $$
>
>   begin
>
>       RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select format(''%s - %s'',min('||$1||E'),max('||$1||E') ) AS min_max_vals from '||$2||E';';
>
>  end
> $$ ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT min_max_vals
> FROM 
>     min_max_val('id','towns')
>     AS t( min_max_vals tEXT)
> ```
>
> ```
> | min_max_vals |
> | :----------- |
> | 1 - 3        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6fdbc27d7326ad908e71a09f070ee7f3)*